# Getting state of screen/phone without waiting for an intent notification

Tags: android, android-intent

I have some intent filters created that work fine but - I only get told what state the screen/phone is in after it changes.  How do I find the current state?  This is my filter -

```
    receiver = new EventHandler();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    filter.addAction(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED); // for calls
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

I get an immediate notification for the battery state even though it hasn't changed.  Would be nice if the other intents fired a dummy notification like that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only get a return on the battery state immediately because `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` is a `sticky` broadcast and is persisted at all times.

The other three are one-shot broadcast intents only sent when the 'action' has occurred. You will need to call methods on the various 'manager' classes to get an instant state.

For example, `TelephonyManager` has a `getCallState()` method and `PowerManager` which has a `isScreenOn()` method.

I haven't tried either myself but the docs suggest they'll work for what you need.

See...

[TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html)

[PowerManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html)

Comment: That looks like the job!  Easy when you know how - thanks so much for the reply.  Peter.